# What is the difference between four 1X dynos and two 2X dynos in heroku?

Tags: heroku

Does anyone know the answer for this? I spawned two 2X dynos on heroku and the performance with the free 1X dyno is much better than the two 2X dynos. They both have the same Rails app talking to the same database. Boggles my mind!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More dynos give you more concurrency. Based on a single threaded web server such as thin, if you have 4 x 1x dynos, you can serve four requests at the same time.

With 2 x 2x dynos you can only serve two requests.

2x dynos have more memory (1024MB) and more CPU available. This is useful if your application takes up a lot of memory. Most apps should not need 2x dynos.

Heroku have recently added PX dynos as well, which have significantly more power available.

You can read about the different dynos [Heroku offers on their website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size#available-dyno-sizes).

Comment: As a further clarification, what if we are running a worker process like Sidekiq that has 25 threads (`:concurrency: 25`). With a 1x Dyno it could perform 25 tasks at once. With a 2x Dyno, it can still only perform the same 25 tasks right? It just has more memory/CPU available? I'm thrown off by the Heroku website saying the "CPU Share is 2x" and the "Compute is 4x-8x" for the 2x Dynos. It's not too clear to me what that means. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The actual data changed since the accepted answer was posted.

The current difference is the memory (512MB for 1x and 1024MB for 2x), as well as the CPU share that is doubled for 2x.

More details can be found on the following Heroku dev center page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types