# heroku workers and delayed job gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, queue, backgroundworker, delayed-job

I know there have been a few posts on Heroku and delayed_job but I am still confused on the interaction between Heroku's workers and background jobs.

So I am launching a new version of my website and I added delayed_job to handle emails. It says that I just add `worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work` to my `Procfile` and I am good to go. But wouldn't that mean that the only worker I am paying for is being use for background jobs? So do I need to get another one then?

Some people also mentioned things like hirefire, which can automatically turn on and off your worker, but that doesn't make perfect sense to me. Shouldn't that worker always be doing stuff for your website already, so if it is ever in use with delayed_job then it isn't running my website. I have a low level of knowledge on how this all works and would love an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah in order to use delayed_job you need to be paying for one worker process.  The worker process will only process your delayed_jobs from the queue, and then your normal web process (they give you one for free) will process all of your web requests.  You scale web and worker processes separately.

A `heroku ps` will show you which processes you have running and you should have at least 1 web and at least 1 worker in order to process web requests and delayed job processes.

You can either use the command line or the web interface to add processes, command line to add your worker would be:

`heroku ps:scale worker=1`

Comment: Ok so I bought one worker and have one dyno. When I bought the worker that made it so my website doesn't delay when people go to my website. If I designate that worker to handle delayed_job tasks, will my site go back to having that delay? Basically will there be an impact on the overall experience on my website?

Comment: If you designate one of your two workers to `delayed_job` then you will go back to where you were before. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001448/what-is-the-difference-between-four-1x-dynos-and-two-2x-dynos-in-heroku) for the difference between Dynos.